# How can I make another request to the server without wait ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, httpresponse

I have a request that takes more than 1 minute (possibly 30 minutes) on my backend-side(PHP) and implemented it as an ajax call.
The problem is that after making this call, if I redirect to another page or make another request to the server to view some data, the page stays waiting until the previous ajax call finishes.

Is there a way to make another request to the server from that page or any other page after the ajax call to continue working?

I searched a lot for cases similar to this problem, but couldn't find what I was looking for.

If this can't be implemented, I even thought of changing the backend logic so that the response time is short in the ajax call and running the time-consuming logic as a cronjob, but I don't want to do this.

I hope someone has a smart solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using file-based PHP sessions? Then you need to call `session_write_close` in your long running script as soon as you are done using the session, otherwise the file lock on the session file will prevent other scripts from accessing that same session.

Comment: My backend is Laravel. Call the Laravel controller.

Comment: Some servers make a queue  with all your requests. If you want send new request to the same service you can use subdomain, v1.domain.com, v2.domain.com or change server config.

Comment: It will be good if you use queue for long running processes. Thus you don't have to keep waiting for the ajax response .